Is there anyway I can connect my simple pythonflask kafka application to AWS EKS?
I have created a small application on my local computer , to get an understanding of how kafka works. I have 3 files Producer.py , Consumer.py and DataGenerator.py . Producer sends messages to the consumer , the consumer file contains code that will just listen to the producer sent messages and the data generator file produces random json files each time you run the file(these are the messages sent to a topic called message in producer). I want to integrate this small application with existing AWS EKS stuff(it was setup by some cloud infra group at my firm) so as to create a small POC so how should i go about doing that ?
Producer.py
import time
import json
import random
from datetime import datetime
from datagenerator import generate_message
from kafka import KafkaProducer

#Message will be serialized as Json
def serializer(message):
    return json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')

#kafka producer
producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers=['192.168.1.214:9092'],
    value_serializer = serializer
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        dummy_message = generate_message()
        print(f'Producing message @ {datetime.now()} | Message @ {str(dummy_message)}')
        producer.send('messages',dummy_message)

        time_to_sleep = random.randint(1,3)
        time.sleep(time_to_sleep)

Consumer.py
import json
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        'messages',
        bootstrap_servers=['192.168.1.214:9092'],
        auto_offset_reset = 'earliest'
    )
    for message in consumer:
        print(json.loads(message.value))

DataGenerator.py
import random
import string

user_ids = list(range(1,101))
recipient_ids = list(range(1,101))

def generate_message()->dict:
    random_user_id = random.choice(user_ids)

    recipient_ids_copy = recipient_ids.copy()

    recipient_ids_copy.remove(random_user_id)
    random_recipient_id = random.choice(recipient_ids_copy)

    message = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(32))

    return{
        'user_id':random_user_id,
        'recipient_id':random_recipient_id,
        'message':message
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(generate_message())

I am running Zookeeper on my local as well , using the Apache Quickstart Guide for Kafka
Way to replicate this would be :
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties - this starts the zookeeper service , do this in one terminal.
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties - this starts the broker service , do this in another terminal
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic messages --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 - do this in another terminal to create the messages topic
once all of this is done , run datagenerator.py to generate a few dummy messages and then run consumer.py,producer.py
